# p5js instance mode and object orientation

Tags: javascript, oop, canvas, instances, p5.js

I have a "sketch.js" where i want to instance multiple canvases und display different objects of one class in them.

### sketch.js:

```
var myObjects = [];

var sketch1 = function (p) {
    p.setup = function () {
        p.createCanvas(600, 400);
    }

    p.draw = function () {
        p.background(51);
        p.rect(p.width/2, p.height/2, 200, 200);
    }   
};

new p5(sketch1, "canvas_container");

var sketch2 = function (p) {
    p.setup = function () {
        p.createCanvas(600, 400);
        myObjects.push(new myObject(p, 1, 2));
        myObjects.push(new myObject(p, 3, 4));
    }

    p.draw = function () {
        p.background();
        for (var i=0; i<myObjects.length; i++) {
            p.line(0, 0, myObjects[i].x, myObjects[i].y);
            myObjects[i].doSomething(Math.random()*10);
        }
    }
};

new p5(sketch2, "canvas_container");
```

When do i use "this." and when "p." in this case?
Furthermore I would like to use some "other" methods from the p5 library in my sketch.js file, outside of the instaces, like:

```
select('..') ...
```

but I get the error:

```
select is not defined
```

I found myself a dirt workaround:

```
new p5().select('...') ...
```

What is the clean way to do this?

### myObjects.js

```
function myObject(canvas, x, y) {
    this.canvas = canvas;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    this.doSomething = function(rad) {
        this.canvas.ellipse(this.x, this.y, rad, rad);
    }
}
```

Has anybody an example for handeling multiple instances of canvases?

Answer (score 0):

Note that right now, you aren't ever creating a new instance of `myObject`. Your array is named `myObjects`, but you're only ever adding `p` (which is an instance of `p5`) to it. So you can't magically call your `doSomething()` function on the objects you've added to your `myObjects` array, because they aren't `myObject` objects. They're `p5` objects.

I think what you would want to do is take the `p` variable passed into each of your sketches and pass that into your "class" functions. Something like this:

```
p.setup = function () {
        p.createCanvas(600, 400);
        var myObjectOne = new myObject(p, 1, 2);
        var myObjectTwo = new myObject(p, 3, 4);
}
```

Then it should work how you're expecting it to.

Comment: Oh yes, I see. sorry this is just some made up code, my focus was actually on the instance mode and how to refer to it as p5 objects. I found this video to be extremely helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Su792jEauZg